# need help for proper commands in libplacebo filter

Tags: command-line, ffmpeg, video

Before you comment guys, let me ask if libplacebo filter only works with vulkan/cuda and not dxva2? Because i've already seen so many examples how to use the `libplacebo` with vulkan/cuda and as for me, it doesn't work whatever i do with dxva2.

**here's my command;**

```
ffmpeg -y -nostdin -bitexact -fflags +bitexact+igndts+ignidx+flush_packets -hwaccel dxva2 -hwaccel_output_format dxva2 -init_hw_device dxva2=hw -filter_hw_device hw -i "/Users/PANASONIC/Downloads/v.mkv" -nostdin -bitexact -fflags +bitexact+igndts+ignidx+flush_packets -hwaccel dxva2 -i "/Users/PANASONIC/Downloads/a.mkv" -bitexact -fflags +bitexact+igndts+ignidx+flush_packets -c:a copy -c:v wmv1 -param1 1.0 -vf "hwupload,libplacebo=1280:720:yuv420p,setsar=1,ass=/Users/PANASONIC/Downloads/nayeon pop.ass,hwdownload,format=yuv420p" -q 0 -threads 0 "D:/01 windows ffmpeg muxer/nayeon pop-1.mkv"
```

**and here's the full CLI output;**

> ffmpeg version n5.0.1-4-ga5ebb3d25e-20220609 Copyright (c) 2000-2022
> the FFmpeg
>
> developers
>
> built with gcc 11.2.0 (crosstool-NG 1.24.0.533_681aaef)
>
> configuration: --prefix=/ffbuild/prefix --pkg-config-flags=--static
> --pkg-conf
>
> ig=pkg-config --cross-prefix=x86_64-w64-mingw32- --arch=x86_64
> --target-os=mingw
>
> 32 --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-debug --disable-w32threads
> --enable-
>
> pthreads --enable-iconv --enable-libxml2 --enable-zlib
> --enable-libfreetype --en
>
> able-libfribidi --enable-gmp --enable-lzma --enable-fontconfig
> --enable-libvorbi
>
> s --enable-opencl --disable-libpulse --enable-libvmaf --disable-libxcb
> --disable
>
> -xlib --enable-amf --enable-libaom --enable-libaribb24 --enable-avisynth --enabl
>
> e-libdav1d --enable-libdavs2 --disable-libfdk-aac --enable-ffnvcodec
> --enable-cu
>
> da-llvm --enable-frei0r --enable-libgme --enable-libass
> --enable-libbluray --ena
>
> ble-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-librist --enable-libtheora
> --enable-lib
>
> vpx --enable-libwebp --enable-lv2 --enable-libmfx
> --enable-libopencore-amrnb --e
>
> nable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenh264 --enable-libopenjpeg
> --enable-libop
>
> enmpt --enable-librav1e --enable-librubberband --enable-schannel
> --enable-sdl2 -
>
> -enable-libsoxr --enable-libsrt --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libtwolame --enable-
>
> libuavs3d --disable-libdrm --disable-vaapi --enable-libvidstab
> --enable-vulkan -
>
> -enable-libshaderc --enable-libplacebo --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enabl
>
> e-libxavs2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-libzvbi
> --extra-cflags=-DL
>
> IBTWOLAME_STATIC --extra-cxxflags= --extra-ldflags=-pthread
> --extra-ldexeflags=
>
> --extra-libs=-lgomp --extra-version=20220609
>
> libavutil 57. 17.100 / 57. 17.100
>
> libavcodec 59. 18.100 / 59. 18.100
>
> libavformat 59. 16.100 / 59. 16.100
>
> libavdevice 59. 4.100 / 59. 4.100
>
> libavfilter 8. 24.100 / 8. 24.100
>
> libswscale 6. 4.100 / 6. 4.100
>
> libswresample 4. 3.100 / 4. 3.100
>
> libpostproc 56. 3.100 / 56. 3.100
>
> Unrecognised hwaccel output format: dxva2Input #0, matroska,webm, from
> '/Users/P
>
> ANASONIC/Downloads/v.mkv':
>
> Metadata:
>
> encoder : Lavf
>
> Duration: 00:02:50.64, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 265377 kb/s
>
> Stream #0:0(eng): Video: ffv1 (FFV1 / 0x31564646), yuv444p(tv,
> bt2020nc/bt709/
>
> bt709, progressive), 3840x2160, SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9, 23.98 fps, 23.98
> tbr, 1k tbn (
>
> default)
>
> Metadata:
>
> ENCODER : Lavc ffv1
>
> DURATION : 00:02:50.643000000
>
> Input #1, matroska,webm, from '/Users/PANASONIC/Downloads/a.mkv':
>
> Metadata:
>
> encoder : Lavf
>
> Duration: 00:02:50.64, start: -0.007000, bitrate: 127 kb/s
>
> Stream #1:0(eng): Audio: opus, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp (default)
>
> Metadata:
>
> DURATION : 00:02:50.641000000
>
> Stream mapping:
>
> Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (ffv1 (native) -> wmv1 (native))
>
> Stream #1:0 -> #0:1 (copy)
>
> [Parsed_ass_3 @ 0000000013634d00] libass API version: 0x1502002
>
> [Parsed_ass_3 @ 0000000013634d00] libass source: commit:
> 0e0f9da2edc8eead93f9bf0
>
> ac4ef0336ad646ea7
>
> [Parsed_ass_3 @ 0000000013634d00] Shaper: FriBidi 1.0.12 (SIMPLE)
> HarfBuzz-ng 4.
>
> 2.0 (COMPLEX)
>
> [Parsed_ass_3 @ 0000000013634d00] Using font provider directwrite
> (with GDI)
>
> [Parsed_ass_3 @ 0000000013634d00] Added subtitle file:
> '/Users/PANASONIC/Downloa
>
> ds/nayeon pop.ass' (2 styles, 61 events)
>
> [Parsed_hwupload_0 @ 00000000136344c0] Query format failed for
> 'Parsed_hwupload_
>
> 0': Invalid argument
>
> Error reinitializing filters!
>
> Failed to inject frame into filter network: Invalid argument
>
> Error while processing the decoded data for stream #0:0
>
> Conversion failed!

**my specs;**

i5-2540M 2c4t
Intel HD Graphics 3000 (with DirectX Computing, OpenGL3.1 , and supported shader version 4.1)
Windows7 64-bit using CLI

Comment: Please make an effort to reduce the command to minimal example that reproduces the problem. Example: `ffmpeg -y -hwaccel dxva2 -hwaccel_output_format dxva2 -init_hw_device dxva2=hw -filter_hw_device hw -i in.mp4 -vf "hwupload,libplacebo=1280:720:yuv420p" out.mkv`. And make an effort and read [this web page](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/HWAccelIntro)